# Сборка приложения из JAR в EXE с JRE

Tags: java

Просто при запуске программы, написанной на Java, на машине, на которой она не установлена - программа, соответственно, работать не будет.
Как решаются подобные вопросы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самые популярное решение [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) или [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) , но это всего лишь Загрузчик приложения на java, то есть jre все равно необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Можете приобрести [Excelsior Jet](http://www.excelsiorjet.com). А можете собрать приложение с помощью gcj. Но размер вас не порадует. Можно собрать с JVM "в пузе", например с JamaicaVM.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас можно купить Excelsior JET всего за $50: http://www.excelsiorjet.com/charity

Answer (score 1):

Установите JRE. иначе никак. преобразование в .exe не спасёт. Ну если очень хочется преобразовать jar -> exe то [вот ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/409290/14145), но jre - обязательный компонент

Comment: То есть приложения, написанные на java без jre вообще нельзя использовать?