# Как в intellije idea сделать исполняемый файл .exe?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, exe

Все перепробовал, закомпиливается проект в .exe но он не запускается и даже никаких ошибок не выдаёт.

Answer (score 2):

Прямого способа создать исполняемый файл .exe в Java нет, разве что Java FX(но не уверен, встречал в инете что можно), но можно создать файл с расширением .jar который также будет запускатся, а потом с помощью программы Launch4j, которая конвертирует файл .jar в .exe . Но, чтобы запустить файл с расширением .jar , на ПК должна быть установлена jdk. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415971/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-jar-%D0%B2-exe-%D1%81-jre) На youtube есть видео как делать jar файлы.

Comment: В `IntelliJ Idea` есть возможность создать `.exe` файл на `JavaFX`.

Comment: Можете рассказать как?

Comment: Вот видео пример создания .jar файла [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA8rEz_xFrQ)  в IntelliJ Idea . Если делаете все правильно, но все равно не запускается, то нужно смотреть код.

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, А зачем вам .exe ?

Ваше приложение все равно без JRE или JDK работать не будет.
Возможно эта ссылка вам поможет

[Не запускается .jar файл с JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006317/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-jar-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-javafx/1006557?noredirect=1#comment1707171_1006557)

Comment: Для удобств запуска на виндовс

Comment: Повторюсь, Если ваша программа написана на Java, то без минимальных JRE или JDK вы не сможете запустить её(имеется в виду на другом ПК с виндой).

Говоря иначе - просто создайте артефакт JavaFx application, и он будет исполняться точно так же как .exe файл.

Comment: В этом и заключается вся фишка "чашки кофе". При установленной JRE или JDK, ваш проект будет работать и на линуксе, и на macOS с одного и того же .jar файла.

Comment: Артефакт `JavaFX Application` - и есть `.exe`.

Comment: Я это понимаю, меня интересует создание самого .exe файла, я сделал на ПК установлена Java JDk, но прога не запускается вообще